# How can I save a Window form in QTableWidget as it was a matrix?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I'm trying to save a `Window form` inside a `QTableWidget` table.

```
int rows = 0;
int columns = 0;
QTableWidget cellTable;
```

What I'm doing is that I first set the rows and columns

```
cellTable.setRowCount(++rows);
cellTable.setRowCount(++columns);
```

For every time I increase the rows, I call this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    cellTable.setCellWidget(rows-1, i, new DatabaseMeasurementType());
```

For every time I increase the columns, I call this code

```
for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    cellTable.setCellWidget(i, columns-1, new DatabaseMeasurementType());
```

It works if I replace the `new DatabaseMeasurementType()` with `new QPushButton()`. But then all the fields will be buttons. For the moment, I just want to store a window form inside the `setCellWidget`. Yes, `new DatabaseMeasurementType()` is a widget form.

**Problem:**

When I call this code (dynamic cast)

```
DatabaseMeasurementType *databaseMeasurementType = static_cast<DatabaseMeasurementType*>(cellTable.cellWidget(row, column));
databaseMeasurementType->show();
```

Or this code (static cast)

```
DatabaseMeasurementType *databaseMeasurementType = dynamic_cast<DatabaseMeasurementType*>(cellTable.cellWidget(row, column));
databaseMeasurementType->show();
```

Then it crash. Why?
My idea is to have a large 2D matrix where I can store windows forms. Then I only need to call `x` and `y` arguments for the 2D matrix to recieve the windows form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting should work if you've inherited from QWidget properly. Casts return `nullptr` if failed. So, it's safier to check if it's failed or not:

```
if(databaseMeasurementType != nullptr){
    //some works with databaseMeasurementType
}
```

It's recommended to use `qobject_cast` if you've written `Q_OBJECT` macro inside your class.

### If you want to show your window outside of the table's cell

- Getting widget and removing it from the table. When you use `setCellWidget` method, QTableWidget change widget's parent because of memory management. Widgets are shown inside their parents. So, you should change it's parent after getting it and remove it from the table. But `QTableWidget::removeCellWidget(int row, int column)` removes the widget and deletes it. `setCellWidget(row, col, nullptr)` also deletes it. So one way to remove the widget without deleting it is wrapping it to another widget.
- Cloning a widget. You should do it manually. One traditional way is to implement custom `QWidget* clone()` method, and cloning member-by-member.